# difference between matplotlib.pyplot.plot() and matplotlib.pyplot.figure()?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

It seems to me figure() is the higher level controller according to the user manual http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html

But any guru further enlighten the differences between figure() and plot()?

Answer (score 3):

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
```

This:

```
plt.plot(range(10))
```

is just a shortcut for:

```
fig = plt.figure()
sub = fig.add_subplot(111)
sub.plot(range(10))
```

The latter gives your more fine-grained control over many things.

Comment: @Chubaka Does this answer your question?